# How do I add multiple roles form a list to a user?

Tags: discord.py, pycord

I have a command that adds all the current roles of a user to a Database (MongoDB).

The code:

```
def add_roles_to_db(self):

    check = cursor.find_one({"_id": self.ctx.author.id})

    if check is None:
        cursor.insert_one({"_id": self.ctx.author.id, "roles": [str(r) for r in self.ctx.author.roles[1:]]})
    else:
        cursor.update_one({"_id": self.ctx.author.id}, {"$set": {"roles": [str(r) for r in self.ctx.author.roles[1:]]}})
```

The code to get the roles:

```
    def get_roles_from_db(self):
        return cursor.find_one({"_id": self.ctx.author.id})["roles"]
```

When I get the roles from the DB I get a list, everything I've tried led to an error. Error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'"

```
if len(roles) != 0:
    await author.add_roles(*roles)
```

I saw a other post where someone added roles via a list but that didn't work

Comment: What error are you getting? How are you getting the roles from the database?

Comment: @moinierer3000 I edited the post with the error and how i get the roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await author.add_roles(*[discord.Object(role_id) for role_id in roles])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a list of strings, not a list of `Role`s. Turn them into `discord.Role` instances using the id's first, and *then* pass them to `add_roles`.

You can get them using [`Guild.get_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Guild.get_role), or [`Guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Guild.roles).

Comment: either im to dumb for this or it doesn't work but i cant get it to work

Comment: @Dr.Troll well I can't exactly smell what you've tried or what the errors are so that's not very useful information

Answer (score 0):

One good way of adding multiple roles to a user is to have the list of role IDs into a list. You would have to look at your code and figure out how to do that bit, as I don't know either but I reckon just append it into a list. Then interate through each item in that list (each ID) and append it.

Example code:

```py
guild = client.get_guild(1234) #replace 1234 with your guild ID
guild = ctx.guild              #this is another way of doing it, chose the one above or this

role_ids = [] #your role ids would be in this list

for id in role_ids:
    role = guild.get_role(id)
    await author.add_roles(role)

await ctx.send("Given you all the roles!")
```

I haven't tried this myself, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

If you need any more clarification, please ask me and if this has worked, please mark it as correct! :)